# PRAW Loop With HTTP Exceptions

Tags: python, python-3.x, reddit, praw

I am using a Python script to loop through a list of subreddits and pull their posts. The list is long, however, and occassionally there will be 403, 404, etc. errors in there. I am attempting to bypass those which give errors, but have been unable to do so thus far. The code is below.

I am using a list of subreddits and praw to pull from them. However, the list is quite long and occasionally a subreddit on it will be deleted, resulting in an HTTP exception (403, 404, etc). My code is below, does anyone know a line or two I can put in to skip those which give errors?

```
df = pd.read_csv('reddits.csv', sep = ',')
df.head()

Submission = namedtuple('Submission', ['time', 'score', 'title', 'text', 'author', 'comments', 'url', 'domain', 'permalink', 'ups', 'downs', 'likes', 'crosspost', 'duplicates', 'views'])
data = []

for i in df.reddits:
    subreddit = reddit.subreddit(i)
    for submission in subreddit.new(limit=10):
            time = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(submission.created_utc)
            score = submission.score
            title = submission.title
            text = submission.selftext
            author = submission.author
            comments = submission.num_comments
            url = submission.url
            domain = submission.domain
            permalink = submission.permalink
            ups = submission.ups
            downs = submission.downs
            likes = submission.likes
            crosspost = submission.num_crossposts
            duplicates = submission.num_duplicates
            views = submission.view_count
            data.append(Submission(time, score, title, text, author, comments, url, domain, permalink, ups, downs, likes, crosspost, duplicates, views))
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    os.chdir('wd')
    filename = i + str(datetime.now()) + '.csv'
    df.to_csv(filename, index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: which line raises the exception? The short answer is to wrap that line in a `try:` block, and do nothing (or better yet, log something useful) in the `except`.

Comment: It is the subreddit = reddit.subreddit(i). I know why it is giving the error, the subreddit list is not fully updated and contains some old subreddits. I just want to continue past those in the list. Some searching indicates that continue: would be an appropriate command, but I am unsure where to insert it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch the exception, then you can `continue`

```py
df = pd.read_csv('reddits.csv', sep = ',')
df.head()

Submission = namedtuple('Submission', ['time', 'score', 'title', 'text', 'author', 'comments', 'url', 'domain', 'permalink', 'ups', 'downs', 'likes', 'crosspost', 'duplicates', 'views'])
data = []

for i in df.reddits:
    try:
        subreddit = reddit.subreddit(i)
    except HTTPError as e:
        print(f"Got {e} retrieving {subreddit}")
        continue # control passes back to next iteration of outer loop
    for submission in subreddit.new(limit=10):
        submission = Submission(
            datetime.utcfromtimestamp(submission.created_utc),
            submission.score,
            submission.title,
            submission.selftext,
            submission.author,
            submission.num_comments,
            submission.url,
            submission.domain,
            submission.permalink,
            submission.ups,
            submission.downs,
            submission.likes,
            submission.num_crossposts,
            submission.num_duplicates,
            submission.view_count,
        )
        data.append(submission)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    os.chdir('wd')
    filename = i + str(datetime.now()) + '.csv'
    df.to_csv(filename, index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

also, unrelated: `i` is not a good name for the value; it traditionally stands for "index", which is not what is contained there. `e` would be the corresponding generic name, standing for "element", but `reddit` would be the idiomatic choice in python.